# Having problems converting a complicated LINQ DataContext C# query to a SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datacontext

I have currently been trying to convert the query string/code below to a SQL query.

If anyone can decode the query, I would be grateful.

```
AtrDataContext orion = new AtrDataContext();
MasterCalculator dcc = (from a in orion.MasterCalculator 
                        where DaysOld >= a.startDayRange 
                           && (!a.endDayRange.HasValue || DaysOld <= a.endDayRange) 
                        select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can you add more details like what's your ORM LinqToSQL or EntityFramework. if EF then which version of EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HasValue is just a null checker. DaysOld seems like it is a variable passed in.  Something like this...

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MasterCalculator a
WHERE a.startDayRange <= @DaysOld
    AND (a.endDayRange IS NULL OR  a.endDayRange >= @DaysOld)
```

Of course, good practice is to specify each of the columns

Comment: Maybe go for 'IS' NULL there

Answer (score 1):

```
Select top 1 * from MasterCalculator where Daysold >= @startDayRange and (@endDayRange is null or DaysOld <= @endDayRange)
```